# How to get raw XPath from Chrome inspector?

Tags: google-chrome, xpath, screen-scraping

When I use Google Chrome's super-cool element inspector to find the XPath of an element, it returns things that don't exist in the original HTML, like `<tbody>`.

Clearly, Chrome infers certain things to make page rendering smoother; that's fine. But I need to use the XPath for scripts outside of Chrome. So I usually get Chrome's XPath, and then use trial-and-error until the XPath actually works in other contexts (in my case, a script written in Python or Node.js).

What is a better technique for finding the "raw" XPath of an HTML element in a given webpage?

Comment: I was going to write that exact same question right now. Have you found a way to disable chrome from autocorrecting? I had the <tbody> issue as well.

Comment: No better solution ever came up. Using relative paths (in the current lone answer) is about as good as it gets, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use full xpaths. If you do, your script will break whenever a single element gets moved.  It's better to find the simplest expression that gives you what you're after. For example the title of this page might be: `//h1[@itemprop="name"]` or even just `//h1`. If your html parser let's you use css selectors, even better - try to use those.